# Как перевести координату (x,y) в индекс массива?

Tags: массивы, алгоритм, координаты

В двумерном массиве, например `arr[5][5]`, значение `arr[0][0]`=0,
`arr[1][0]=1`, `arr[3][0]=3` ... `arr[0][1]=5` и т.д. по порядку,  т.е. `arr[x][y]` это координаты.

```
    4 [20][21][22][23][24]
    3 [15][15][17][18][19]
    2 [10][11][12][13][14]
    1 [ 5][ 6][ 7][ 8][ 9]
    0 [ 0][ 1][ 2][ 3][ 4]
        0   1   2   3   4
```

Как перевести значение, например 12, с координатой (2,2) в индекс одномерного массива  `arr[12]`, что бы этот элемент обозначал конкретную координату (2,2),  элемент `arr[19]` - координату (4,3) и т.д.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Мне кажется, вас интересует для массива `arr[ROWS][COLS]` получение номера ячейки в одномерном представлении

```
N = COLS*y + x
```

У вас `COLS=5`, так что для (4,3) получаем 3*5+4 = 19, например...

и, соответственно, обратного преобразования

```
y = N/COLS   
x = N%COLS
```

Опять же, для `N=19` имеем `y = 19/5=3`, `x=19%5=4`.

Если нет - поясните подробнее, что вас интересует...

Comment: То что нужно! Спасибо!